# The homogeneous sobolev space and the Fourier transform

Tags: lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

What is a sufficient condition for $s>0$ such that

$$\mathcal{F} \dot{H^s} (\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$$

where $\dot{H^s} (\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the homogeneous sobolev space: $\dot{H^s}= (- \Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}} L^2$,

$\mathcal{F}$ stand for the Fourier transform,

$\mathcal{F} \dot{H^s} =\{f \in \mathcal{S}^{\prime} ; \mathcal{F}^{-1} f \in  \dot{H^s} \}$, and

$||f||_{\mathcal{F} \dot{H^s} } = ||\ |x|^s f\ ||_{L^2}$.

Comment: It seems this is mainly a problem of notation. You meant $||f||_{\mathcal{F} \dot{H^s} } = ||(1+ |x|^s) f\ ||_{L^2}$ ?

Comment: No,  $||f||_{\mathcal{F} \dot{H^s} } = ||\ |x|^s f\ ||_{L^2}$.

Comment: In that case there is no inclusion.